# does phonegap support older version of symbian

Tags: mobile, symbian

Does phonegap supports programming older versions of symbian ( < s60 v5)? Anybody tried usig it for graphics and network programming (somewhat intensive use)? I am interested for medium to highend symbian phones with at least 320x240 screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap uses Nokia's web runtime (WRT) which is available on S60 3rd Edition Feature Pack 2 (or 3.2 for short), S60 5th edition (aka Symbian^1) and Symbian^3 and later (Symbian Anna and Belle).

From the [Phonegap website](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494780/Getting%20Started%20with%20Phonegap%20Nokia%20WRT):

> Phonegap for Symbian is dependent upon Nokia's Web Runtime (WRT), which is included on Symbian S60 5th Edition and S60 3rd Ed. FP2.

I've never used Phonegap so cannot answer the second part of the question.